# Do i really require two tables design for this case?

Tags: mysql

I am planning to store global indices live in my database .
as shown in this link

https://in.finance.yahoo.com/intlindices?e=asia

To store so , i have come up with the following design

```
CREATE TABLE regions(
    region_name varchar(100),
) 


CREATE TABLE index_values(
    region_name varchar(100),       
    country_name varchar(50),
    symbol_name varchar(50),
    LastTradePrice varchar(20),
    ChangeinPercent varchar(20),
    Changeinpoints varchar(20),
    LastTradeTime varchar(20),
    FOREIGN KEY reg_index(region_name)
    REFERENCES regions(region_name)
)
```

My question is that i really dont see any use of making two tables ??
                 Can i proceed with one table or am i missing anything ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you intend to use your data. If you're planning to mostly read from index_values and read performance is important, then it's a good approach to denormalize all data into this one table and you could delete the "regions" table and the foreign key to it.

If, on the other hand, you foresee wanting to rename a region at one point, it would be advantageous to separate the regions in a different table "regions" so you only have to update one region record instead of all index_value records with that region. In that case you'd want to remove the region_name field from the index_values table.

You may want to read up on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization.

Sidenote: I'd consider a different name for your table because indices are an important part of databases, it's too confusing. Perhaps "financial_indices".